# Division overflow on assembly

Tags: assembly, overflow, x86-16

I'm doing this exercise for university and my assembler returns me an overflow during a division, i did step by step debug checking registers but I can not solve the problem because I'm not able to find it.
I post the code so you could try to help me.
The goal of the program is to multiply the number of coins for the respective value, for example I have 10 coins of 1 euro, so I have 10 euros; I have to save into memory how much money I have in total; coins and values are in two vectors and they are respectively joined by position.

The code is for an Intel 8086

```
.model small
.stack
.data
value dw 1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200
coins db 100,23,17,0,79,48,170,211
euro dw 0
cent dw 0
.code
.startup
mov si,0   ;must arrive on 8
mov di,0
mov bx,100 ;to separate euro and decimals
mon: mov al,coins[si]
cbw
mul value[di]
div bx
add cent,dx
add euro,ax
inc si
inc di
inc di
cmp cent,100
jb cicl
mov ax,cent
mov cent,0
mov dx,0
div bx
add euro,ax
mov cent,dx
cicl: cmp si,8
jnz mon
.exit
end
```

Hope my code is clear.
Thank everybody and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: `Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual
Volume 2 (2A, 2B & 2C):
Instruction Set Reference, A-Z`, Section of `div`: *Unsigned divide DX:AX by r/m16, with result stored in AX ← Quotient, DX ← Remainder.* Where did you set `DX` to a sane value?

Comment: That's assuming that the assembler treated `mul value[di]` as a `mul r/m16`

Comment: Replace `cbw` by `mov ah,0` .

Comment: If the numbers in your *value* array represent EUROS, then your calculation is wrong with respect to the division by 100. **Multiplying whole euros by another whole number will always give you whole euros.** The *cent* part inevitably must be zero.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `cbw` is giving the wrong value to AH register, so let's change it by `mov ah,0`, here's your code (I'm getting the result 634.11, is that correct?) :

```
.model small
.stack
.data
value dw 1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200
coins db 100,23,17,0,79,48,170,211
euro dw 0
cent dw 0
.code
.startup
mov si,0   ;must arrive on 8
mov di,0
mov bx,100 ;to separate euro and decimals
mon: mov al,coins[si]
mov ah,0                  ;<========================================= cbw
mul value[di]
div bx
add cent,dx
add euro,ax
inc si
inc di
inc di
cmp cent,100
jb cicl
mov ax,cent
mov cent,0
mov dx,0
div bx
add euro,ax
mov cent,dx
cicl: cmp si,8
jnz mon
.exit
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mon:
>  mov al,coins[si]
>  cbw
> ```

You got 2 *coins* values (170 and 211) that will fault when you use the `cbw` instruction to extend the value. Better use `mov ah,0`. As an alternative you could define the coins array as **word** and then simply write `mov ax,coins[si]`. This would of course require you to double `inc` the SI register and compare SI to 16 in stead of 8 for the loop control.

---

> ```
>  cmp cent,100
>  jb cicl
>  mov ax,cent      !?
>  mov cent,0       !?
>  mov dx,0         !?
>  div bx           !?
>  add euro,ax      !?
>  mov cent,dx      !?
> cicl:
> ```

What you're doing here is way too complex! The `div bx` instruction (with BX=100) left a remainder of max. 99 in the DX register and so you know that on each iteration the *cent* variable can at most be raised by 99. Use this fact and simplify the code to:

```
 cmp cent,100
 jb cicl
 sub cent,100
 inc euro
cicl:
```